# UIImagePickerController image not changing

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using the `UIImagePickerController` to allow the user to select a photo from their library. I then want to assign the chosen image with this code;

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
 UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
 [users_pic_ setImage:image];
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But the users pic never changes.

`users_pic_` is defined as: `UIImageView* user_pic_;`

Anybody notice anything wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use this code -

```
// make sure to allocate users_pic_

UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; 
users_pic_.image = image; 
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: The problem turned was that the UIImageView was not properly initialized. I allocated in my viewDidLoad method (it was previously setup in Interface builder via a XIB file) and then the [users_pic_ setImage:image] worked.